# Is there any simulator for Container migration in the fog?

Tags: fog-computing

I'm trying to simulate a Container-based [fog environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_computing) with a few servers and mobile devices. Devices connect to the nearest server and the service is implemented within Containers. Those Containers have to migrate to other servers for various reasons (latency reduction, load balancing, etc.).

The simulator has to take factors like bandwidth, processors, and memory into account and be able to implement different migration methods (i.e. cold, pre-copy, post-copy and even hybrid).

I want to develop an algorithm for my thesis to dynamically decide when and how to migrate the containers and I need to implement it in a simulated environment as proof of effectiveness. I should analyze the whole system and present factors like bandwidth usage and average latency between devices on charts.

Is there such a tool to cover all my needs?

Comment: Are you seeking for a way to know the resources of the node or seeking a resource management tool? Or are you only looking for a tool to duplicate the node environment ? The title of the question + your post doesn't really give a clear question.

Comment: well, I want to develop an algorithm for my thesis to dynamically decide when and how to migrate the containers and I need to implement it in a simulated environment as proof of effectiveness. I should analyze the whole system and present factors like bandwidth usage and average latency between devices on charts.

Comment: Please clarify if you want emulation (i.e. an actual system), or simulation (a parameterised model using representative bandwidth estimates, etc). I just realised I voted to keep this open even though the requested clarification is absent.

Comment: A simulation will do fine. But is has to caver different migration methods as described. @SeanHoulihane